# в чем разница между значениями «embed» и «isolate» в css свойстве «unicode-bidi»?

Tags: html, css

Пожалуйста, смотрите примеры. Там я написал код для этих двух значений, которые дают одинаковый результат.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hayti</title>
  <style>
   p
    {
       direction: ltr;
    }
   span
    {
       background-color: yellow;
       direction: rtl;
       unicode-bidi: embed;
    }
    
   .p01
    {
       direction: ltr;
    }
   .span01
    {
       background-color: yellow;
       direction: rtl;
       unicode-bidi: isolate;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Two samples </h1>
    <p> Programming in <span>Html and CSs!!</span> is the easiest way to learn coding. </p>
    <p class="p01"> Programming in <span class="span01">Html and CSs!!</span> is the easiest 
    way to learn coding. </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Результат`

*---embed----* Programming in **!!Html and CSs** is the easiest way to learn coding.

*----isolate----* Programming in **!!Html and CSs** is the easiest way to learn coding.

Comment: В статье [unicode-bidi | htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/css/unicode-bidi) с примерами объясняется зачем и как.

Comment: но там ничего не написано про " isolate "  значение......